# Problema con login, app ReactNative en dispositivo físico, fallo de conexión

Tags: javascript, login, react-native, yarn

tengo un problema con la conexión de una aplicación, está creada con react native,el portatil es un AMD con windows 10, y el teléfono movil tiene sistema Android.

Os paso el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sucede es que cada vez que hago login, bien esté vacio, o bien tenga un usuario y contraseña (que ya está en la base de datos registrado).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucede esto

¿Cómo se llega a esto?, vamos por pasos:

1º- Conecto el dispositivo por USB (tanto el usb como el cable están en buen estado, ya se ha revisado, no es por eso).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ha ejecutado  el comando **adb devices** en terminal, se puede ver que el dispositivo está conectado.

2º- Se ejecuta el comando **yarn android,** se empieza a ejecutar y se va instalando en el dispositivo la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el comando, se va instalando en el dispositivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instalación exitosa de la App en el dispositivo físico.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero **ahora viene el problema**: Se quiere comprobar si hay conexión, así que lo que se pretende es ver cómo responde con un usuario que esté registrado y hacienda un login vacío, y ver cómo responde la aplicación.

Os paso la función de login, para que veáis el código

```
_loginAsync = async () => {
// reinit error states
this.setState({emailError: '', passwordError: '', errorMessage: ''});

console.log('start login');

//FIXME: ONLY FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT SETTING LOGIN OFF
//this.props.navigation.navigate('App');

try {
  auth
    .authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('auth response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      if (response.error) {
        if (typeof response.error === 'object') {
          Object.keys(response.error).forEach(type => {
            this.setState({[type + 'Error']: response.error[type]});
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({errorMessage: response.message});
        }
      } else {
        //FIXME: ONLY FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT SETTING LOGIN OFF
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
      }
    })
    .catch(exception => {
      console.log('auth exception: ' + exception);
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log('auth error: ' + error);
}
```

};

Adjunto imagen del inspector del dispositivo físico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí añado el index.js

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/MMBBAA/6ca2eab4115d287d9949a34b6fbc6f5d.js"></script>
```

Comment: hasta donde tengo entendido, Android pide que las conexiones a servidores sean `HTTPS`, si tienes `http`, es probable que el dispositivo te bloquee

Comment: lo he comprobado y parece que con https funciona, creo que no es eso, he editado la parte final de la pregunta para que tengas una visual.

Comment: ¿Cómo así? ¿Al definir `http`, funciona o deja de funcionar?

Comment: Quiero decir que continuaba sin poder conectarse, aunque te permitiera cargar la app. Se ha resuelto, luego expondré la solución, ha sido complicada y hemos tenido que sacarla adelante entre varias personas.

Comment: ¡Eeeepaaa! Felicitaciones, esperamos la respuesta, serás el héroe de más usuarios con el mismo escenario y/o algún escenario similar, gracias por la buena intención de colaborar con la comunidad :D

Comment: Lo he logrado a medias, algunas veces funciona y otras no, no es un fallo de conexión,el método fetch funciona,pero hay algo mal en alguna parte,algunas veces funciona y otras no, es inestable.

Comment: Subo un código a ver si ayuda

Comment: la solución ya está encontrada, el asunto se ha arreglado de esta manera:

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, ya tiene la solución adjuntada

Comment: Bro, las respuestas tienen su área en la parte inferior de esta página donde hay un text area que dice "Tu Respuesta", edita la pregunta, mueve ese fragmento y luego de 24 horas marca esa respuesta como aceptada, ayudarás a mantener el orden del sitio y serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo problema o algo muy parecido :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARREGLADO: se ha reparado de esta forma:

1º-se borra este archivo android\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out

2º-Adjunto el código del loginPage que funciona con esto:

try {

```
auth
.authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password)
.then(response => {
  console.log('auth response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  if (response.error) {
    if (typeof response.error === 'object') {
      Object.keys(response.error).forEach(type => {
        this.setState({[type + 'Error']: response.error[type]});
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({errorMessage: response.message});
    }
  } else {
    //FIXME: ONLY FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT SETTING LOGIN OFF
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  }
})
.catch(exception => {
  console.log('auth exception: ' + exception);
});
```

} `catch (error) {
  console.log('auth error: ' + error);
}`